# Plot a wave on a surface

Tags: graphics3d

Say I'm plotting a 3d-ring with

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
  Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

I need to plot a wave, like a sin-function, which runs over the surface of the ring. Something like a mesh line, which is not straight, but oscillates?

Is it possible to plot?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this?

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]},
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  With[{t = v, u = 0.5 Sin[20 v]},  
    {Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]}
   ],
  {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Thick]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

You can draw a `Sin` like curve in the parametric domain,see `f[t,u]` as below.

```
f[t_, u_] := 2 u - 1 - Sin[15 t];
ContourPlot[f[t, u] == 0, {t, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, FrameLabel -> {t, u}]
```

[image]

and then use the `MeshFunctions` to lift it to the surface.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
  Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan], 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, t, u}, f[t, u]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

**Original**

Like this?

```
f[x_, y_, k_] := 4 Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - k]*Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/6];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
   Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan], 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, f[u, v, k]], Mesh -> 40, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {k, 0, 8/π, 1/(50 π)}]
```